# RoboSpice or DataDroid for local SQL DB syncing using WiFi Direct and/or BT connected Android devices?

Tags: android, synchronization, wifi-direct, robospice, datadroid

I need to have two or more Android devices connected via WiFi Direct(preferably) or BT that share a DB stored on each device. The DB can be updated by any of the connected devices and must send out the changes and update any/all devices running the app that are connected to the Wifi Direct network. I really prefer/can't use a remote server for this app.

1. Is it possible to hook in RoboSpice, DataDroid, or another library I don't know of to handle the threading and data updating?
2. If it's possible, would the UI of the app be updated on screen upon reception of new remote DB updates(eg. changing the list content currently showing to the updated info received remotely)?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit: Using a wifi router(not internet connected) as an access point may be allowed in the solution if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

That would be possible with RoboSpice. Maybe the most suited module would be the experimental ormlite content provider. This module is still in beta but you can find it in the repo. That would give you a mechanism based on content observers to update your UI when DB is updated.

But, even without this module, RS could do the job, you would have to a service that uses a spice manager and send data in background. It's gonna be a fairly technical app.

Comment: I did a little more research and I can open a new question if it seems unrelated. Looks like I would need to use a router for an access point and enable a service discovery for my app to handle 2+ devices as WiFi Direct/BT are P2P.I guess the next question is how does RoboSpice handle socket connections once my devices discover each other? I'm kind of new to this, but I assume the devices would be using sockets to send each other info to update their peers databases...correct? Each client would have to listen for changes...mcast? Can RoboSpice take care of the message reception and DB updates?

Comment: Really it's too fuzy for me to answer here. Sorry not to help, best is to try.